# Django filters just returns all objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

So I have model like this

```
class Research(models.Model): 
    CATEGORIES = (...)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    date = models.DateField()  
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CATEGORIES)
    public_use = models.CharField(max_length=17, choices=PUBLIC_USE_CHOICES)
```

This filter:

```
class ResarchFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    year = filters.DateFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='year')
    category = filters.CharFilter(field_name='category', lookup_expr='iexact')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Research
        fields = ['date', 'category']
```

And that view:

```
class ResarchCategoryYear(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Research.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ResearchSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    # filterset_fields = ['date', 'category']
    filter_class = ResarchFilter
```

urls:

```
path('rsch/filter/cat', ResarchCategoryYear.as_view(), name='rsch_date_cat_view'),
```

So when I'm uncomment filterset_fields and comment filter_class it all works well but I can't filter by the year and not by the full date. So when I'm do it like in code above and goes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/...?year=2000`
It literally do nothing, just gives me all of the Research objects.
So what I'm doing wrong and how to enable this filtering?

Comment: As noted in the [django-filter documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/main/guide/rest_framework.html#adding-a-filterset-with-filterset-class) as well as the [django-rest-framework documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#overriding-the-initial-queryset) it should be `filterset_class` instead of `filter_class`

Comment: @shriakhilc thanks a lot! Yeah it was just my lack of attention. Changed to ```filterset_class``` and now it working as expected

Answer (score 0):

In the django-filter [docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#declaring-filters), they create a year filter from a datefield as a *numberfilter*, rather than a datefilter - which makes a kind of sense as you are taking an integer (the year) from the date context

So you might have better luck with:

```
year = filters.NumberFilter(field_name='date', lookup_expr='year')
```

Comment: Yeah make some sense. But still my page do kinda nothing